# Create LESS source map files with WebEssentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

According to the WebEssential log LESS souerce maps are supported since Version 1.6 (January 2, 2014) for VS2013 (http://vswebessentials.com/changelog)

I have Version 1.9 for VS2013 installed. **But source maps are not being generated.**
What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image: less compilation result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to activate the generation of map files in the Web Essential settings.
Just open `Tools` > `Options` > `Web Essentials` > `LESS` in Visual Studio and set `Create source map files` to true.

In addition make sure the web server you are using delivers .less files on request. 
For IIS 7.0 you can do so by following the instructions at:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

As mime type select `text/css`.

Comment: I think this setting is not working since the  2.3 - August 7, 2014  update of WebEssentials.