# How to create LESS source map files with Web Essentials (web compiler) 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, web-compiler

Where is Web Essentials (web compiler) options to generate map files in VS 2015? 
In 2013 it was just "Tools -> Options -> Web Essentials" in current version Less options is pretty hidden. I want to have map-files and compile on build. Is it possible by web essentials/web compiller 2015?

Here is answer to my question for Web Essentials 2013: 
[Create LESS source map files with WebEssentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707968/create-less-source-map-files-with-webessentials)

Answer (score 0):

I believe here is the answer to your question: [Link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee6e6d8c-c837-41fb-886a-6b50ae2d06a2)

All new extensions listed: [Link](http://webtooling.visualstudio.com/extensions/web-development/)

Comment: Ok, so How to create LESS source map files with Web Essentials 2015 and those bunch of plugins?

Comment: I didn't get a chance yet to use it, but I recommend reading through the readme file on [WebCompiler GitHub page](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/). It seems easy enough.

Comment: yes, but I don't see answer. Where is source map settings in Visual Studio 2015 IDE?

Comment: The readme file states it should be in `compilerconfig.json` file.

Comment: Can I have map files, if I don't want any compilerconfig.json files? Web essentials 2013 does not require any config files all settings was in IDE menu.

Comment: I don't really think so, I had similar problem with my `.min.js` files, I need `bundleconfig.json` now.